# TWICImage: How to overlay transparent PNG on JPG?

Tags: delphi, graphics, png, delphi-10.2-tokyo, wic

For example, we have a base image in jpg format:
[image: base jpg] [base jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0nyp.jpg)
And the overlay image in png format:
[image: transparent png] [transparent png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVXkk.png)
This image I want to get as a result of their merger:
[image: result]
My question is: how to get this result using the power of TWICImage?
I can load both images like this:

```
function DoMerge: TWICImage;
var
  wicJPG,
  wicPNG: TWICImage;
begin
  wicJPG := TWICImage.Create;
  wicPNG := TWICImage.Create;
  try
    wicJPG.LoadFromFile('base.jpg');
    wicPNG.LoadFromFile('overlay.png');
    Result := wicJPG + wicPNG;  // (pseudo-code) how?
  finally
    wicPNG.Free;
    wicJPG.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can  create a `B: TBitmap`. pseudo: `B.Assign(wicJPG); wicPNG.Draw(B.Canvas); Result.Assign(B);`.

Comment: @kobik [dcc32 Error] E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TWICImage.Draw

Comment: Probably a stupid question but anyway: why not to use `TPngImage` supplied with Delphi instead of playing around with `TWICImage`?

Comment: @Dima WIC is typically intended for arbitrary image formats, when you don't know the type.  So indeed, if OP only cares about PNG, I would expect it to directly use `TPngImage`, but if it might be in another format, that would be why.

Comment: @JerryDodge thank you. Your explanation made things more clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about `TWICImage` except that its a `TGraphic` descendant.
So you can *try* something like this:

```
var
  B: TBitmap;

B := TBitmap.Create;
try
  B.Assign(wicJPG); 
  B.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, wicPNG);
  Result := TWICImage.Create;
  Result.Assign(B);
finally
  B.Free;
end;
```

I can't test it now.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But I would like to use only WIC features (without involving TBitmap). Is it real?

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be possible via the `IWICImagingFactory` or `IWicBitmap ` interfaces it uses.

Comment: AFAIK, WIC images are read-only if I remember right. Meaning, it's not meant to manipulate images. That's what the `TBitmap` is meant for.

Comment: @JerryDodge, After looking at the documentation, one probably can get the `TWICImage.Handle` which returns a `IWICBitmap` and using the [`IWICBitmap::Lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmap-lock) method get access to the underlying pixels data, and copy the needed overlay data into the source. good luck with that... ;) seems like the Delphi `TWICImage` wrapper is very limited.

Comment: Yeah, I think Borland originally expected that any image manipulation be done on a `TBitmap`.

Comment: @kobik, Ok, I will accept your answer if there is no other (using TWICImage only) within 24 hours :)